# url does not load after proxy settings in IE and burp suite

Tags: security, burp, pen

When I set proxy to record activities in Burp Suite, URL keeps on loading, though manually without proxy it works.

Answer (score 0):

When intercept is turned on, Burp Suite should be intercepting the request. The request should appear in the Proxy "Intercept" tab. Are you able to see the http request in this tab?

We have two tutorial pages to help you use Burp Proxy within our Support Center, have you checked these out?

- https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783118-getting-started-with-burp-proxy
- https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783119-using-burp-proxy

For new users we also recommend that you follow all of our tutorial articles to gain a better understanding of Burp Suite - https://support.portswigger.net/.

Comment: I could see the request when Intercept is turned on, but the response is invalid and the dashboard never comes up.

Application workflow in detail,

Issue is with proxy settings in IE:

1. Url is typed and the browser pops up dialog for authentication.
2. After the valid credentials input the browser will not load the dashboard

Error: XYZ.com address not found
Also observed that the response was Unauthorized access(Even though credentials are valid) in one of the HTTP history response

Note: Without proxy settings in IE the application will be launched successfully

Comment: Hi @san Can I suggest you turn off Intercept while you're getting this working. You may also need to enter your Windows credentials into the Platform Authentication section which is in User options > Connections.

Comment: I have tried by turning off intercept. Not sure what is happening, the authentication pop up keeps on coming as if it is wrong credentials (which is indicated in response ). The credentials are very much valid because same it works fine when proxy is off in the browser.. Can anyone let me know what are all the parameters I have to see to debug this scenario.

Comment: It did work with Platform authentication settings. thanks @PortSwigger